# Find value between minimum and maximum

Tags: c#

```
 public static double valore(double value_in)
 {
    var minimi = new List<double>();
    minimi.Add(4.55);
    minimi.Add(4.75);
    minimi.Add(5.1);
    minimi.Add(5.6);
    minimi.Add(5.9);
    minimi.Add(6.1);
    minimi.Add(6.5);
    minimi.Add(7);
    minimi.Add(7.4);
    minimi.Add(7.8);
    var massimi = new List<double>();
    massimi.Add(4.65);
    massimi.Add(4.85);
    massimi.Add(5.35);
    massimi.Add(5.75);
    massimi.Add(6.05);
    massimi.Add(6.35);
    massimi.Add(6.65);
    massimi.Add(7.25);
    massimi.Add(7.65);
    massimi.Add(7.95);
    var values = new List<double>();
    values.Add(4.6);
    values.Add(4.8);
    values.Add(5.2);
    values.Add(5.6);
    values.Add(5.9);
    values.Add(6.2);
    values.Add(6.5);
    values.Add(7.2);
    values.Add(7.4);
    values.Add(7.9);
    for (int j = 0; j < values.Count; j++)
    {
        var minimo = minimi[j];
        var massimo = massimi[j];
        if (value_in >= minimo && value_in < massimo)
        {
            value_in = values[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    return value_in;
}
```

Hi All.

I have to find in the fastest way if "value_in" is between one minimum and the relative maximum so as to change its value.

Then i have to find in the fastest way the nearest maximum when a value is not between a minimum and the corresponding maximum.

For example if i call

double my_value=valore(4.7);

it returns 4.7 but i would like to know the value of the nearest maximum(4.8)

I don't want to know the list containing the value. minimi and massimi won't change and yes i need it for a lot of istances. I would like to break the iteration when for example 4.7 is over its maximum value even if it is not between a minimum and a maximum . Then i was thinking if it would be faster to insert the value in the list, then sorting the list and picking the index.... and i'm googling binary tree now

Comment: SO you want to get the next maximum value right? and you want to check in which list?

Comment: well, 4.7 doesn't satisfy any of the criteria, so it returns whatever you passed in. You need to store the minimum and maximum values separately, and then compare each in `values` to those stored numbers.

Comment: You could potentially make use of Binary trees to solve the problem, can't you? Sure, .NET doesn't have Tree implementations available but I'm sure you can find a Nuget package with Tree implementations in them.

Comment: The presented algorithm has a linear runtime, which apparently is optimal; a potential improvement is only possible if, for instance, `minimi` and `massimi` don't change and the problem has to be solved for various instances of `values`.